# updating records with image dimensions to database. I want to wait less than 10 hours

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, execution-time

I have a large mysql table of raw images of over 1,200,000 rows (1 row per image) in innoDB format but I'll be working with about 600,000 of the rows. What I want to do quickly is retrieve the local image filename from the database, and determine the size and dimensions of it and then store the details back into the database.

Performing I/O on the database without image calculations is fast because I have mysql settings configured optimally. In fact, I configured one buffer to be larger than the entire size of the largest mysql database file size.

Currently, my code for calculating image dimensions and size is this:

```
$img='/path/to/current/image/to/find/dimensions/for.jpg';
$ifs=-1;
$iw=-1;
$ih=-1;
if ($ifs=@filesize($img)){
$im=NULL;
$im=@imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
if ($im){
    $iw=imagesx($im);
    $ih=imagesy($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
$im=NULL;
}
```

Is there a way to convert this code into a format that takes substantially less time to execute?

Remember. I'm dealing with local images and the code above is in the process of being executed 600,000 times, so optimizations are important here, and any code that saves me even one millisecond of execution time will be appreciated.

All images in question are in jpeg format and sizes often range from 600x400px to 800x533px

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you've already considered where you're saving the image file, i.e. a RAM disk or similar?

Comment: All the images are in their set locations on a HDD on a server and that can't change. I'm making the updates on a server while its running because the database is too large to download and then re-upload and I have too small of a hard drive on my local machine to handle all the images and plus I don't want to pay for extra bandwidth.

Comment: Ah, I misread. I thought you were extracting the images from the database.

Answer (score 1):

There is a user comment on php.net in the documentation of [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) that does not read the entire jpeg file to find out the dimensions, since the dimensions are stored after the header part of the file. The code is jpeg specific, cannot be used for other file types.

This code should be faster than yours, since it dies not read the entire file and does not create a resource out of it.

```
<?php
// Retrieve JPEG width and height without downloading/reading entire image.
function getjpegsize($img_loc) {
    $handle = fopen($img_loc, "rb") or die("Invalid file stream.");
    $new_block = NULL;
    if(!feof($handle)) {
        $new_block = fread($handle, 32);
        $i = 0;
        if($new_block[$i]=="\xFF" && $new_block[$i+1]=="\xD8" && $new_block[$i+2]=="\xFF" && $new_block[$i+3]=="\xE0") {
            $i += 4;
            if($new_block[$i+2]=="\x4A" && $new_block[$i+3]=="\x46" && $new_block[$i+4]=="\x49" && $new_block[$i+5]=="\x46" && $new_block[$i+6]=="\x00") {
                // Read block size and skip ahead to begin cycling through blocks in search of SOF marker
                $block_size = unpack("H*", $new_block[$i] . $new_block[$i+1]);
                $block_size = hexdec($block_size[1]);
                while(!feof($handle)) {
                    $i += $block_size;
                    $new_block .= fread($handle, $block_size);
                    if($new_block[$i]=="\xFF") {
                        // New block detected, check for SOF marker
                        $sof_marker = array("\xC0", "\xC1", "\xC2", "\xC3", "\xC5", "\xC6", "\xC7", "\xC8", "\xC9", "\xCA", "\xCB", "\xCD", "\xCE", "\xCF");
                        if(in_array($new_block[$i+1], $sof_marker)) {
                            // SOF marker detected. Width and height information is contained in bytes 4-7 after this byte.
                            $size_data = $new_block[$i+2] . $new_block[$i+3] . $new_block[$i+4] . $new_block[$i+5] . $new_block[$i+6] . $new_block[$i+7] . $new_block[$i+8];
                            $unpacked = unpack("H*", $size_data);
                            $unpacked = $unpacked[1];
                            $height = hexdec($unpacked[6] . $unpacked[7] . $unpacked[8] . $unpacked[9]);
                            $width = hexdec($unpacked[10] . $unpacked[11] . $unpacked[12] . $unpacked[13]);
                            return array($width, $height);
                        } else {
                            // Skip block marker and read block size
                            $i += 2;
                            $block_size = unpack("H*", $new_block[$i] . $new_block[$i+1]);
                            $block_size = hexdec($block_size[1]);
                        }
                    } else {
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
?>
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I'll see if I can come across something a bit simpler as well.

Comment: Simpler in what terms?

Comment: The code is given to you, you just have to copy-paste. I wonder if a php extension would contain this exact same code, but the complexity would be hidden from your eyes because it is compiled and you were told to simply use that function, then would you call that a simpler solution? Btw, have you tried the suggested solution? Does it work? Does it save you time?

Comment: not yet but if I try a solution and it fails, then I'll probably have to start rescanning the database of 600,000 records again which takes more time.

Comment: I'm running my code on the largest table (600,000 records) because I know it works, but the problem is its damn slow. I let it ran already for 8 hours and only 1/2 the table is done

Answer (score 0):

I've used this JPEG size code before, it may actually be based on the code posted in the other answer!

Prepared statements will save a lot of overhead with the database inserts.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$db     = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=images", "username", "password");
$images = $db->query("SELECT id, filename FROM images", PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$stmt   = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO images SET width = ?, height = ? WHERE id = ?");

foreach ($images as $image) {
    list($w, $h) = jpgsize($image[1]);
    $stmt->execute(array($w, $h, $image[0]));
}

$db->close();

function jpgsize($img) {
    $h = fopen($img, "rb") or return false;
    $block = null;
    if(feof($h)) {
        fclose($h);
        return false;
    }
    $block = fread($h, 32);
    if (substr($block, 0, 4) === "\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0" && substr($block, 6, 5) === "\x4A\x46\x49\x46\x00") {
        $block_size = unpack("H*", substr($block, 4, 2));
        $block_size = hexdec($block_size[1]);
        $i = 4;
        while(!feof($h)) {
            $i += $block_size;
            $block .= fread($h, $block_size);
            if(substr($block, $i, 1) === "\xFF") {
                $sof_marker = array("\xC0", "\xC1", "\xC2", "\xC3", "\xC5", "\xC6", "\xC7", "\xC8", "\xC9", "\xCA", "\xCB", "\xCD", "\xCE", "\xCF");
                if(in_array(substr($block, $i+1, 1), $sof_marker)) {
                    $size_data = substr($block, $i + 2, 7);
                    $unpacked = unpack("H*", $size_data);
                    $unpacked = $unpacked[1];
                    $height = hexdec(substr($unpacked, 6, 4));
                    $width = hexdec(substr($unpacked, 10, 4));
                    fclose($h);
                    return array($width, $height);
                } else {
                    $i += 2;
                    $block_size = unpack("H*", substr($block, $i, 2));
                    $block_size = hexdec($block_size[1]);
                }
            } else {
                fclose($h);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($h);
    return false;
}
```